Как сохранить файл Python
Я вообще не понимаю во всяких этих file.save(. . .) и тд. Мне просто нужно сохранить переменную в файл на Python. Напишите, пожалуйста, простой def, который просто сохраняет отдельный файл на устройстве с заданным именем и данными внутри файла.

Смотря что за данные. Можно простенький json записать с помощью библиотеки json и метода dump.

from pathlib import Path; Path("file.txt").write_text(some_text). Если записать нужно не строку, то преобразовать сначала json.dumps(...)

Я? Я посоветую воспользоваться вашим советом :-) ......
Если действитвельно сохранить, чтобы потом когда угодно посмотреть глазами или другим инструментом, то json. A если граф произвольных объектов для следующего запуска, то можно и pickle. ......
А еще у меня сайт есть, 20 лет работает, на перле, там все данные вот примерно в таких бинарниках по фс раскиданы. Очень удобно однако.

def save_to_file(name, data):
    file = open(name, 'w')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()

save_to_file('example.txt', '123')


В учебниках для этой цели рекомендуют использовать модуль pickle. Пример:
import pickle

# Пример объекта для сохранения
data = {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'city': 'New York'}

# Сохранение объекта в файл
with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)

# Загрузка объекта из файла
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    loaded_data = pickle.load(file)

print(loaded_data)


В учебниках да. Но на практике бодаться с разными версиями pickle и не иметь возможности посмотреть файл глазами как-то не вдохновляет. Json гораздо удобнее.

В документации данный модуль работает и с самой последней версией Питон 3.13.1. Я не знаю, с чем там бодаются, кто и зачем. Если там есть проблемы, обоснуйте невозможность и ненужность использования. Кроме того, модуль позволяет сохранять более умно, чем просто текст писать в файл.

Ну вот запишите вы в пикл последней версией питона, а потом кто-то со старой версии попытается прочитать и не сможет. Можно при записи выставить совместимость на уровень определённой версии, но в любом случае это дополнительные телодвижения. Поэтому кроме как в учебниках и таториалах пикл обычно и не используют.

Это разговоры ни о чём. Кто? Что? Где? Я не работаю со старыми версиями. Потребителям распространяется вообще только автономная сборка, сделанная с помощью pyinstaller, следовательно всё, что нужно на борту. Если бы да кабы, а вдруг чё случится, ой, всё пропало, ужас, ужас... Это не обо мне. У меня работает. И авторов учебников тоже.

Так почитайте эти учебники и убедитесь. Они существуют не только для школьников и для самовосхваления, но и для самообучения. Например, я изучаю Питон по учебникам. Именно учебникам, для студентов вузов. Сначала были школьные.
